# Entity Framework 4.0 reference tables not showing?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have 3 tables:

Client (fields: client_id, name)
Permissions (fields: perm_id, title)
Client_Permissions(fields: client_id, perm_id)

Client permissions fields are foreign keys to client and permissions table.

When I import scheme to Entity Framework, Client_Permissions not showing...

Any explanation how so? and how can i update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF generates the reference for you as properties on the Client and Permissions objects (each should have a collection pointing to the other)

You can manipulate them in code without knowing the details of the DB schema, or having to worry about keeping them up to date.

This is one of the advantages of an ORM